# Spring and JavaMail connection timeout

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to do email confirmation via gmail host. And i continue getting "Connection timeout 500 error"
I tried change params in app properties, and in configuration class. Change port to 465 insteed 587, and nothing helped me.

***If you found this page unreadable, which might be... there's link on full project with full stack trace --->*** https://github.com/OlegSokolyk/sweater

**here's my app prop:**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=mailsendtestsweater@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=vhmixskurxwrymtu
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.debug=true
```

**MailConfig class:**

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${mail.debug}")
    private String debug;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);
        mailSender.setUsername(username);
        mailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", debug);

        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

**MailSender service:**

```
@Service
public class MailSender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;


    public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String message) {

        try {
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

            mailMessage.setFrom(username);
            mailMessage.setTo(emailTo);
            mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mailMessage.setText(message);

            mailSender.send(mailMessage);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Registration method:**

```
public boolean addUser(User user) {
        User userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if(userFromDB != null) {
            return false;
        }

        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        userRepository.save(user);

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Hello, %s! \n " +
                            "Welcome to Sweater. Please, visit next link: http://localhost:8080/activate/%s",
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getActivationCode()
            );

            mailSender.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", message);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**Registration controller:**

```
@PostMapping("/registration")
    public String addUser(User user, Model model) {

        if (!userService.addUser(user)) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "User exists");
            return "registration";
        }

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

**Stack trace:**

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
>   Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
>   nested exception is:  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out:
>   connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
>   Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
>   nested exception is:

Comment: The FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  Try those and let us know what happens.  If it still doesn't work, post the [debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was my internet provider. I tried the same code in antoher one and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000

try adding above two properties